# Quantas sílabas tem a palavra "menino" em pt-PT?

Tags: português-europeu, divisão-silábica

Um traço do pt-PT falado que observamos facilmente é a frequente omissão de vogais que não estejam na sílaba tônica.  Dessa forma,"menino" é pronunciada [mni.no], "competentes" =  [comp.ten.tes], "diferente" = [di.fren.te], etc.  No momento de classificar tais palavras de acordo com o número de sílabas, "menino" é considerada dissílaba?  "Diferente" é considerada trissílaba?  A classificação é baseada unicamente no português falado?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Dada que a divisão em sílabas tradicionalmente é fonética, eu esperaria que "diferente" fosse trissílaba em pt-PT,; mas muitas vezes a fonética parece perder a preponderância (chegando-se, às vezes, ao ponto de ser igualada à separação em partes para a translineação!), então não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Graficamente a divisão silábica em Portugal é a mesma que no Brasil; mas isto só é relevante para a translineação. Foneticamente, que é o que nos interessa aqui, o número de sílabas de muitas palavras depende no português europeu do cuidado e velocidade com que falas. *Menino* (e analogamente na outra palavras que indicaste) reduz-se realmente a duas sílabas, [’mni.no], na fala coloquial rápida, mas mantém três sílabas na fala cuidada ou pausada, [mɨ’ni.nu] (a plica, ’, indica que a sílaba seguinte é a tónica). O [ɨ] é um som vocálico que não existe na pronúncia brasileira, e que podem ouvir [aqui](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds-version-3/) (em cima e ao centro no esquema das vogais).

Para a classificação das palavras quanto ao número de sílabas, os dicionários que mostram a transcrição fonética mostram a pronúncia cuidada, com o mesmo número de sílabas que a palavra tem no Brasil. O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa indica [mɨ’ni.nu], tal como o faz o [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=3655&highlight=%5Emenina$). A [Infopédia (Dicionário da Porto Editora)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/menino) usa [ə] no lugar de [ɨ] (coisa pouco recomendável na minha opinião), indicando igualmente três sílabas, [məˈninu].

Agora, muitos portuguese nem terão consciência de reduzirem habitualmente *menino* a duas sílabas, e se insistires que o fazem até te poderão responder com uma pronúncia enfática, “três sílabas: [mɨ – ’ni – nu]”. Esta pronúncia enfática ocorre naturalmente em linguagem tipo mãe-perdendo-a-paciência-com-o-filho:

> O [mɨ – ’ni – nu] vai ficar ca – la – dinho e comer tu – do! Ouviu?

Podem ouvir estas três pronúncias de *menina* [aqui no Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/menina/#pt): no topo temos o usuário Aimae com uma pronúncia cuidada; logo abaixo, o Andreamado com uma pronúncia rápida; e mais abaixo, o Felpo com uma pronúncia enfática.

Também *diferente* se reduz a três ou mesmo duas sílabas na fala rápida, [di’fɾẽ.tɨ] ou [di’fɾẽt], mas mantém as quatro sílabas na pronúncia cuidada, [di.fɨ’ɾẽ.tɨ]. Podem ouvir [no Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/diferente/#pt) a pronúncia cuidada do usuário Jelowa; comparem com a [pronúncia de *frente*](https://forvo.com/word/frente/#pt) do mesmo usuário.

Há um artigo no [Instituto Camões, *A Pronúncia do Português Europeu*](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/cpp/acessibilidade/capitulo3_2.html) que aborda pormenorizadamente esta questão. Cito algumas partes mais relevantes (o artigo mostra a pronúncia com o alfabeto fonético internacional; creio que mesmo quem o não conheça adivinhe o seu valor com a ajuda do contexto; mas podem ver valor [neste artigo da wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) ou ouvir [no site que já indiquei acima](https://forvo.com/word/menina/#pt)):

> A vogal elevada e centralizada [ɨ] é quase sempre *suprimida* na fala coloquial em determinados contextos ([u] também pode sê-lo mas com menos frequência).
>
> Quando a vogal representada ortograficamente por < e > está no início de palavra e é seguida por < s > e consoante, como em *estar, esbater, esconder,* realiza-se como [ɨ] mas é regularmente suprimida (*estar* [’ʃtaɾ], *esbater* [ʒbɐ’teɾ], *esconder* [ʃkõ’deɾ])

Repare-se que *estar* fica reduzido a uma sílaba, [’ʃtaɾ], *esbater* e *esconder*, a duas.

> Quando a vogal [ɨ] está entre duas consoantes, seja em posição pré-tónica ou pós-tónica, a sua supressão é habitual (*meter* [mɨ’teɾ] → [m’teɾ],  *despegar* [dɨʃpɨ’gaɾ] → [dʃp’gaɾ], *velocípede* [vɨlu’sipɨdɨ] → [vlu’sipd], *ómega* [’ɔmɨgɐ] → [’ɔmgɐ]; a vogal [u] neste contexto pode também ser suprimida (*psicologia* [psikulu’ʒiɐ] → [psiklu’ʒiɐ])).

Veja-se como as cinco sílabas de *velocípede* na pronúncia cuidada se reduzem a duas, [vlu’sipd], na fala coloquial rápida; na verdade [vlu’sipt]; a combinação [pd] não dá jeito nenhum.  O artigo fala ainda das consequências da supressão do [ɨ] em fim de palavra. *Velocipede* já é um exemplo disso, mas há outras consequências, que podem ler lá (que digitar os símbolos do alfabético fonético internacional não é pera doce).

Comment: Excelente. Agora [vlu’sipt] é exagero. ;)

Comment: Respostas desse calibre só merecem aplausos. (através de "upvotes", é claro)

Comment: @Centaurus, obrigado; ainda bem que gostaste.

Comment: @stafusa, de 5 para 2 é chocante, mas eu consigo pronunciar [vlu’sipt] facilmente. Provavelmente tu também: todas aquelas combinações de sons existem no português atual; [vl] não é nativo, mas foi importado, e.g. "Vladimir"; [pt] existe por exemplo em "elíptico". Onde eu tenho dúvidas é no [dʃp’gaɾ]: eu acho que habitualmente pronuncio [dɨʃpɨ’gaɾ]; mais relaxadamente, [tʃpɨ’gaɾ]; [tʃp’gaɾ] acho que não consigo.

Answer (score 0):

Ao contrário, a separação de sílabas no Português é relativa à língua escrita! 
Em Português a separação de sílabas não é puramente fonética!

Assim, "menino" é trissílaba e separa-se como "me-ni-no"; "Diferente" é polissílaba (no caso, possui quatro sílabas) e separa-se como "di-fe-ren-te".

Comment: Olá AleAssis, bem vindo. Você poderia citar fontes para suas afirmações? Entendo que "sílaba" é um conceito fonético, como se vê em qualquer dicionário, na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADlaba) ("Sílaba é uma emissão de voz completa, representada por um ou mais fonemas") e no [FLIP](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/880): `A sílaba é um conceito fonético, fonológico ou prosódico bastante intuitivo para os falantes de uma língua e a divisão silábica é feita deste ponto de vista e não do ponto de vista ortográfico.`

Answer (score 0):

Foneticamente a palavra pode ser pronunciada até com uma única sílaba.

Vejamos a frase:

> O menino é bem comportado.

De forma pausada será pronunciada:

> u mɨ.nˈi.nu ˈɛ bɐ̃j kõ.puɾ.tˈa.du

Mas falando um pouco mais depressa poderá ser:

> u mnˈi.nw ˈɛ bɐ̃j kõ.puɾ.tˈa.du

Mas o comum é a semivogal desaparecer:

> u mnˈi.n ˈɛ bɐ̃j kõ.puɾ.tˈa.du

Ou seja, ficamos com:

> O **mnin** é bem comportado.