# Pronúncia dos is e us no Brasil

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronúncia, fonologia

O artigo sobre [Fonologia da Língua Portuguesa na Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) indica para o Brasil, ou melhor, para São Paulo, dois pares de fonemas próximos: [i] e [ɪ]; e [u] e [ʊ]. Em qualquer dos casos em Portugal existe apenas o [i] e [u]. Eu ouvi o [ɪ] e [ʊ] neste [tabela de sons do Alfabeto Fonético Internacional](https://web.uvic.ca/ling/resources/ipa/charts/IPAlab/IPAlab.htm). Aliás o [ɪ] é bem nosso conhecido do inglês. *Ship* é com [ɪ], contrastando com *sheep*, que é com [i] ou [iː]; diferença de que eu muitas vezes me esqueço, exceto no caso de *sheet*. Mas nunca me dei conta de dois is diferentes ou dois us diferentes nos sotaques brasileiros.

Então o que eu gostaria de ver exemplos de palavras onde esses [ɪ] e [ʊ] ocorrem. Existem algumas regularidades, que nos permitam saber pela grafia ou tipo de palavra se é [i] ou [ɪ]? Se é [u] ou [ʊ]? Estas diferenças são peculiares de São Paulo ou estendem-se a outras regiões?

Comment: Não é só em São Paulo, embora os exemplos de outras regiões possam diferir. Eu diria que os 'o's finais frequentemente são [ʊ] no sotaque paulista (e.g., "muito", "burro"). Me parece que em alguns dos sotaques nordestinos os 'e's são muitas vezes pronunciados como [ɪ].

Comment: @stafusa Isso acontece apenas nas sílabas átonas, não?

Comment: @tchrist Não apenas. Por exemplo, às vezes se escreve *cumé qui é?* para "como é que é?".

Comment: @stafusa A [versão portuguesa dessa página](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) menciona o som [ʊ] apenas quatro vezes, mas [a versão inglesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology) menciona o mesmo som onze vezes: parece haver mais informação sobre esse fenômeno na versão em inglês.

Comment: @tchrist Bem notado. É mesmo bastante comum os verbetes da versão em inglês da Wikipedia serem mais completos e em geral bem melhores que os em português, especialmente em assuntos técnicos.

Comment: @tchrist, obrigado pela dica. Tem de facto mais informação. Espero que alguém troque aquilo por miúdos.

Comment: @stafusa, o  [ʊ] poderá ocorrer em palavras como *c**o**ração*? Em Portugal esse **o** é reduzido a [u], de forma que *coração* e *curação* (termo antigo para "cura") ficam homófonos. Eu parece-me que muitos brasileiros também reduzem esse **o**, mas fico com a ideia que não tanto como os portugueses.

Comment: @Jacinto, não lembro de já ter ouvido "coração" pronunciado no Brasil como "curação", no máximo com um [ʊ]: se acontece, acho que é raro.

Comment: @stafusa, estive a ouvir [*coração* no Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt) e parece-me ouvir no Brasil tudo, desde c[ɔ]ração até c[u]ração. Ouve por exemplo a Janainamourão, o Guapetin ou o Rican69.

Comment: @Jacinto Nasci e cresci no Brasil, mas não tenho conhecimento sistemático da pronúncia brasileira (e sei pouco de fonética, por isso inclusive não ofereço uma resposta), mas nunca ouvi um nativo falar c[u]ração. Inclusive não ouço [u] de nenhum dos 3 usuários que você menciona - inclusive o Rican69, que, aos meus ouvidos, apenas fala rápido, mas pronunciaria no máximo um [ʊ] - você ouve um [u] dele? - para mim é quase claro um [o]. Será que as vogais às vezes mais abertas do pt-PT tornam aos ouvidos portugueses um [ô] em um [u]?

Comment: @Diego, a mesma coisa que em relação aos "contínuos", embora aqui até consiga dar uma interpretação às aspas. E a minha referência aos us é possivelmente imprecisa. Pelos vistos são alguns oo que são pronunciados [ʊ]. Mas o corpo da pergunta clarifica.

Comment: @Jacinto Coloquei as aspas apenas para destacar os fonemas no título, pois não são palavras comuns.

Comment: @Diego, pensei que tivesse sido essa a tua ideia. Na verdade, estritamente, a palavra "us" refere a letra e não o fonema, o que torna a minha redação imprecisa. Mas eu por vezes, e é prática aceite aqui no site, sacrifico precisão no título para tentar torná-lo mais simples ou apelativo.

Comment: Eu ouço o fonema `[ʊ]` e `[ɪ]` com bastante regularidade no meu dialeto em um contexto específico que chamo de "final átono": os finais ⟨-o(s), -e(s), -a(s)⟩ de palavras paroxítonas e proparoxítonas (*"sonho(s), carro(s), óculos, febre(s), molde(s), bípede(s), palavra(s)..."*) e de monossílabos átonos (*"do(s), no(s), pro(s), e, de, se, me, lhe(s), a(s), da(s), na(s)"*).

Comment: O final átono é realizado de formas diferentes pelo Brasil: `[ʊ, ɪ, ə]` nos dialetos nortistas e metropolitanos; os regulares `[u, i, ɐ]` na maioria dos dialetos; e os mais abertos `[o, e, a]` no dialeto gaúcho ao sul.  Como exemplo da pronúncia do final átono no dialeto gaúcho, ouça as gravações do gaúcho [Alexstorn](https://forvo.com/user/alexstorn/) no forvo. Como exemplo de dialeto nortista ouça as gravações do [muriloko](https://forvo.com/user/muriloko/).

Comment: @Seninha, eu consigo ouvir bem a diferença no gaúcho; já no tipo do norte, não consigo distinguir o [ʊ] dele do meu sotaque. Ou o meu ouvido não é suficientemente apurado, ou então eu pronuncio também [ʊ]. Este [ʊ] e [u] deveriam ser considerados alofones e não fonemas, não? Já o [ɪ] creio que distingo; mas parece-me que em *cearense* ele pronuncia [e], não?

Comment: Sim, são alofones. O `[ɪ]` é intermediário entre `[i]` e `[e]` (o mesmo para `[ʊ]`, que é realizado entre `[u]`e `[o]`) então é um pouco difícil de distinguir e certas vezes soa ambíguo. Mas realmente, o *-e* final dele é mais notável e menos variável do que o *-o* na fala desse rapaz. Aliás, em Lisboa o *-e* átono final se pronuncia `[ɨ]`, né?

Comment: O [artigo da Wikipedia anglófona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology) sobre a fonologia portuguesa fala um pouco sobre a pronúncia dos finais átonos (que no artigo são chamados de *"unstressed and final vowels"* em uma das tabelas) e sobre a realização `[ʊ, ɪ]` dessas vogais nos dialetos brasileiros, além de citar algumas fontes. Os artigo da wiki em inglês são bem mais completos e com mais fontes do que os em português, ainda que o assunto do artigo seja a língua portuguesa, o que é uma pena, quando eu tiver tempo livre quero me dedicar a traduzi-los.

Comment: @Seninha, então olha, se quiseres aproveitar o trabalho e responder a esta pergunta...  Eu acho que o -*e* final átono nos sotaques mais comuns em Portugal simplesmente não é pronunciado: *leite* soa como o inglês *late*; *cal* (da parede) soa como (é imperioso que ele se) *cale*. Mesmo entre duas consoantes: o trocadilho da canção *Cale-se* do Chico Buarque não funciona no meu sotaque -- *cale-se* aqui soa como *calce* (a bota) e não como *cálice*. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5457/quantas-s%C3%ADlabas-tem-a-palavra-menino-em-pt-pt).

Comment: @stafusa tem razão, os sotaques nordestinos usam `[ɪ]` freqüentemente. Eu não acredito que o uso do fonema se limite de maneira a podermos extrair uma regra que sugira regularidade.

Comment: `[ʊ]` confunde-se muito com `[u]` e `[o]`. Os paulistas costumam usar `[u]` no fim de palavras e muitas vezes no começo, mas não é uma constante. A presença de um som similar na mesma palavra pode levar a uma das vogais ser mais recolhida que outra. Por exemplo, as palavras "colhido" = `/koʎidu/` e "doido" = `/doidu/` têm dois fonemas para "o" e "pato" = `/ˈpatu/` só um. `[ʊ]` é atípico, creio que seja uma versão "fraca" de `[u]`. Esses fonemas são peculiares da região centro-sul (SP, RJ) e comuns na televisão. Mas no sul, por exemplo, essa tendência não tem muita tração.

Comment: Não existe  [ɪ] em português. Por isso, os lusófonos tendem a dizer: He doesn't know sheet em vez de shit. Para os que falam português, francés e espanhol, ship, bit, lit sai tudo errado, tipo sheep, beat, leet. Claro, alguns dominam o som. Acho engraçada que ninguém tenha dito isso.

Answer (score 3):

Realmente, em Portugal não existe uma distinção clara entre os sons [i] e [ɪ] ou entre [u] e [ʊ]. Porém, no Brasil, principalmente em São Paulo, esses pares de fonemas são distintos e a diferença pode ser percebida em pares mínimos, ou seja, pares de palavras que se diferem apenas por um som. Seguem alguns exemplos:

[i] e [ɪ]: tigela / tijela, filha / filha, rima / rimã, fila / filha, pingo / pinga.
[u] e [ʊ]: surdo / surdo, curto / curtou, suco / soco, burro / buru.
É importante ressaltar que não há uma regra clara que indique qual som deve ser usado em cada palavra, mas é possível perceber algumas tendências. Por exemplo, as palavras que possuem a vogal tônica fechada [i] tendem a ter [ɪ] na variante paulista, enquanto as palavras com a vogal tônica aberta [ɛ] tendem a manter o [i]. Já as palavras com a vogal tônica [u] podem ter [ʊ] na variante paulista, especialmente em palavras monossilábicas.

Essas diferenças são peculiares da variante paulista do português falado no Brasil, mas podem ocorrer em outras regiões também. Vale lembrar que as variações de pronúncia dentro de uma mesma língua são comuns e esperadas, e que a variedade paulista é apenas uma dentre as diversas variações do português falado no Brasil.

Comment: O son [ɪ] não existe em português....bit, fit, minute.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que seja falante de uma variedade europeia, então vou explicar fazendo um paralelo com as variedades de Portugal. O fone [ɨ], que ocorre, por exemplo, no fim das palavras em PE, é equivalente ao [ɪ], o fato de este ser exatamente um meio termo entre [e] e [i] faz todo sentido — um exemplo é a palavra gent**e**, dita com o [ɪ] originado de um [e]. O [ʊ] é equivalente ao [u] átono, como no fim de palavras, como em *burr**o***, soa como mais ou menos um meio termo entre um [u] e um [o]. Mais ao sul do pais isto é mais evidente.

Portanto, não é exclusivo a São Paulo, é extremamente comum e é natural que falantes (especialmente de PE) não se deem conta, já que não é um som distintivo (um fonema) e por não possuírem este som no inventário, apenas um muito parecido, o [i] (o mesmo é válido para o u). Tudo isso é o resultado de uma redução vocálica menor, uma maior preservação, do que a que ocorreu em Portugal no século XVIII.

No sul do Brasil ocorre um fenômeno interessante. Sabemos que em muitos dialetos brasileiros temos os sons [t͡ʃ] e [d͡ʒ], como em **t**ia e **d**ia. Em São Paulo, assim como no Rio de Janeiro, este som ocorre sempre antes de um som bem palatal (como [i] e [ɪ]). No sul, no entanto, esta palatalizacão só aconteceu antes de [i], como em *tia* e *dia*, mas não antes de um [ɪ], então palavras como *dente*, que possuem um [ɪ] antes de [t] e [d] não são palatalizadas e são realizadas como [ˈdẽtɪ].